# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 68)

Tags: laravel

I am with this issue TokenMismatchException
in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 68).

In the head of my master.blade.php i have

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and this one

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
  });
  });
```

in the footer.

here my snippet shift.blade.php

```
<div class="modal fade" id="shift-show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Nouveau shift</h4>
        </div>
        <form action="{{ route('createShift') }}"  method="POST"  id="frm-shift-create" >
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <input type="text" name="shift" id="shift" class="form-control" placeholder="Shift">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Fermer</button>
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Enregistrer</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

this one is my route

```
Route::post('gerer/cours/shift',['as'=>'createShift','uses'=>'CoursController@createShift']);
```

when adding {{ csrf_token() }} in my form it returns a blank blank page with no error in my begugger

I am noob in laravel,i see many kinds of these questions here but didnt resolve my issue. Can i get a help?

Comment: Whats inside your `CoursController@createShift`?

Comment: public function createShift(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax())
        {
           return(Shift::create($request->all()));
        }
    }

Comment: Have you tried adding `csrf_field()` inside the form?

Comment: like this      '<form action="{{ route('createShift') }}"  method="POST"  id="frm-shift-create" >
                {{ csrf_token() }}'

Comment: No, `{{ csrf_token() }}` and `{{ csrf_field() }}`are different. Add `{{ csrf_field() }}` inside  the form or `<input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

Comment: ok thanks but it returns a blank page with no error even in the debugger @VandolphReyes

Comment: It's because you're using ajax in your controller and your just making a simple post form. Try using only `dd($request->all())` inside `createShift`

Comment: I do it like this  `    public function createShift(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax())
        {
           return(Shift::dd($request->all()));
        }
    }` but returns blank page again

Comment: You can't get results from that code that's why it's showing you blank space. Use can't use `$request->ajax()` because you're not using ajax. Use `$request->all()` to get results. I hope you got it now.

Comment: I use $request->all() where and instead of what. I am a noob @VandolphReyes

Comment: What do you mean? You can now use your data using `$request` like for example `$request->shift`.

Comment: you are right  but i can't resolve my problem yet...for my case what can i do with the controller createShift or what modification can i do ? thanks again

Comment: What problem do you still encounter???

Comment: according to your explication ,using data with $request is my issue. what might be the content of my controller createShift to avoid blank space

Comment: Please follow the two steps I created for you. https://bin.fuelphp.com/snippet/view/OJ

Comment: for this time i got this       `array:2 [▼
  "_token" => "ZxULpCd7IAyklKz7BDZpmlQeARdhizjU3z7ilfcs"
  "shift" => "Morning"
]`

Comment: Great! You can access the value of `shift` by using `$request->shift`. Is your problem now solved?

Comment: sound good ...but  $request->shift  will be placed where? sorry for this question

Comment: To where you want to use it. I guess I need to end this convo now.

Comment: i mean wrong thing maybe but when i do  $request->shift; nothing change

Comment: Thamk you @VandolphReyes it is done!!! off my hat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read comments below your post, and [Vandolph Reyes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5455156/vandolph-reyes) had clearly resolved your problem, but let's explain one more time.

The `TokenMismatchException` exception said that your form misses the [`CSRF token protection`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf).

You inserted the `CSRF token` in your `<head>` and added this one into **AJAX** HTTP request header, but with your current form, you clearly don't use an "**AJAX** request", so your javascript snippet is unuseful.

In order to add the `CSRF token` in your form, there are two solutions:

1. Add `{{ csrf_field() }}` into your form. It will add a hidden field with the token, and will correct the problem.
2. Add `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />`. That's this field which is generated with the first solution.

With that, you can now access your inputs in the targeted controller action (`CoursController@createShift`) with the help of `$request` or `request()`. For instance, if you are looking for your "shift" input value, you will find it in `$request->input('shift')` (or `$request->shift`).

So now, you can store your value in a database, or use it in an other view/action/controller...

Comment: I need to store "shift" in database and when done,by  submit action will return my master.blade.php. i am biginner sorry for many questions...now i don't know how to use $request->shift in my controller or in my cours/popup/shift.blade.php where exactly. right know i got something like this `array:2 [▼
  "_token" => "NOHXZy0LH3IGvRb4PfUmzTFlEXdDTzQ1WY6qb3vp"
  "shift" => "Morning"
]` only .

Comment: You wrote it before, but it needs a little update: `public function createShift(Request $request) { $shift = Shift::create($request->all()); return view('YOUR_VIEW_FILE', compact($shift)); }`. You will be able to get your shift data with `$shift` into the view you will specified.

Comment: Thanks somebody really explains it again. iArcadia thanks. Welcome @BarthFoxIdman, its okay to ask but not too much. Try to do more also than questioning a lot. Goodluck :)